Z coordinates are missing in sfc geometry in R
i'm literally new in programming and R. I have set of street networks and the segments of each network has been exploded by using QGIS. After using st_read, I found that the type of geometry of my sfc street network is MULTILINESTRING, which is supposed to be LINESTRING.
> library(sf)
> library(spNetwork)
> library(tmap)
> library(tidyverse)
> library(tmaptools)

> # Import street shp file
> street_cakung <- st_read(dsn = "Akademik/Semester 7/Final Boss TA/File GIS/Analisis R Studio/Data SHP/Kecamatan/Street_Cakung.shp")
Reading layer `Street_Cakung' from data source 
  `C:\Users\daksa\Documents\Akademik\Semester 7\Final Boss TA\File GIS\Analisis R Studio\Data SHP\Kecamatan\Street_Cakung.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 57230 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
Dimension:     XY, XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: 710319.8 ymin: 9312174 xmax: 718316.9 ymax: 9319672
z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S```

And then, I try to cast by using st_cast and it works splitting the MULTILINESTRINGS object hence it shows the result
st_cleaned <- st_cast(street_cakung,to = "LINESTRING")

Geometry set for 57233 features 
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: 710319.8 ymin: 9312174 xmax: 718316.9 ymax: 9319672
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S
First 5 geometries:
LINESTRING Z (714868.2 9318798 0, 714876.2 9318...
LINESTRING Z (714940.4 9315617 0, 714937.4 9315...
LINESTRING Z (717801.7 9317100 0, 717796.6 9317...
LINESTRING Z (717473.8 9313510 0, 717473.6 9313...
LINESTRING Z (713879.8 9313725 0, 713879.7 9313...

However, when i try to analyze it using lixelize_lines by spNetwork package, it shows error:
> # Calculating lixels to use as sampling points
> lixels <- lixelize_lines(st_cleaned,300,mindist = 50)
Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 14201)

When I observed the data.frame at the nrow == 14201, I found that this object is missing Z value or Z coordinates so it's just read as matrices 2x2 (XX, YY) while the correct one should be matrices 2x3 (XX, YY, ZZ). There are several objects may miss z value too. The print result is:
st_geom <- st_geometry(st_cleaned)
> st_geom[[14201]]
LINESTRING Z (713989.2 9318923, 713989 9318930)

I'm really confused to how can I store the z values so it has (0, 0). Any solution for this? I'm really thankful if anyone would help me
I have been trying to use st_zm to force add Z coordinate but it doesn't work and show errors
> st_zm(st_cleaned$geometry[[14201]], drop = FALSE, what = "Z")
Error in st_zm.sfg(st_cleaned$geometry[[14201]], drop = FALSE, what = "Z") : 
  adding Z only supported for XY geometries


Are the z values 0 for every correct linestring?

@LTyrone yes, i can make sure every correct linestring has z values 0. It is because my network street only stored in XY data. I m not pretty sure why after exploding it in QGIS making the geometry has z-values. Also, idk which one the correct solution, either making all object has dim = XYZ or making all object dim XY.

Ultimately, the most robust solution is to find out why QGIS added the z dimension in the first place, and then stop this occurring if possible. However, here is a repex based on your data and comment that outlines different options:
Packages and data:
library(sf) # sf_1.0-16
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1.4

# Create example sf with XY and XYZ dimension features
set.seed(1)
sf_lines <- data.frame(latitude = runif(5, min = 9312174, max = 9319672),
                  longitude = runif(5, min = 710319.8, max = 718316.9)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 32748) %>%
  st_union() %>% 
  st_voronoi() %>%
  st_collection_extract() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  st_zm(0, drop = FALSE, what = "Z")
 
sf_lines1 <- sf_lines[5,] %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  select(X, Y) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 32748) %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  rbind(sf_lines[1:4,], .)

sf_lines1
# Simple feature collection with 5 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY, XYZ
# Bounding box:  xmin: 703753.4 ymin: 9306626 xmax: 724935 ymax: 9326044
# z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
# Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S
#                                x
# 1 LINESTRING Z (703753.4 9306...
# 2 LINESTRING Z (703753.4 9326...
# 3 LINESTRING Z (724935 931121...
# 4 LINESTRING Z (718257.5 9318...
# 5 LINESTRING (714198.5 931337...

If you try adding z values to the entire dataset:
sf_lines1 <- st_zm(sf_lines1, 0, drop = FALSE, what = "Z")

it will return this error:

Error in st_zm.sfg(X[[i]], ...) :
adding Z only supported for XY geometries

That's because some of your linestrings already have z values. If you really need to, you could add the z values individually:
sf_lines1[5,] %>% st_zm(sf_lines1[5,], 0, drop = FALSE, what = "Z")

# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XYZ
# Bounding box:  xmin: 714198.5 ymin: 9306626 xmax: 724935 ymax: 9315172
# z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
# Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S
#                                x
# 1 LINESTRING Z (714198.5 9313...

but this would be impractical if there are many missing z values. And given you do not need them, the easiest way to deal with your issue is to drop all z values:
# Drop z dimension
sf_lines1 <- st_zm(sf_lines1, drop = TRUE, what = "ZM")

sf_lines1
# Simple feature collection with 5 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 703753.4 ymin: 9306626 xmax: 724935 ymax: 9326044
# Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S
#                                x
# 1 LINESTRING (703753.4 930662...
# 2 LINESTRING (703753.4 932604...
# 3 LINESTRING (724935 9311210,...
# 4 LINESTRING (718257.5 931800...
# 5 LINESTRING (714198.5 931337...

